# Complexity of adding log n log n operations

Tags: algorithm, math, logging, complexity-theory

I am trying to analyse an algorithm that in the worst case does

`log(1) + log(2) + log(4) + log(n_i) + ... + log(log(n))`

amount of work. Where the n_i's are powers of 2.

My attempt is to say that since:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n
```

is O(n^2), my algorithm is O(log(n^2)) = O(2log(n)).

Is this correct?

Further, I would only expect each of the log(n_i) terms to occur with an independent probability of 0.5. So, can I claim that the above has an *expected* complexity of O(2log(n)/2) = O(log(n))?

Comment: Hint: Use log(2^i) = i*log(2) to rewrite each term.  Now factor out the log(2) factor from each term.  Notice that this factor is a constant.

Comment: So, by factoring: i*log(2) + (i+1)log(2) + ... + (log(n))log(2) = log(2)*(1+2+3+...+log(n)) = 1*(1+2+3+...+log(n)) = O(log(n)^2) ?

Comment: The last term is not log(n).  You need to play with it first, to get it in the form x*log(2), so that you can then factor out the log(2).

Comment: Ok, Timothy Shields answer below led me to it. So obviously lb(n)=lb(2^lb(n)), in my case replacing n with lb(n) I get lb(lb(n)) = lb(2^lb(lb(n)) = lb(lb(n))*lb(2) and I can factor out the lb(2)'s, and ignore it because it is a constant 1. So 1 + 2 + ... + lb(lb(n)), then following my own reasoning this is obviously O(lb(lb(n))^2). Thanks j_random_hacker!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Deterministic analysis

lb(1) + lb(2) + lb(4) + ... + lb(lb(n))

= lb(2<sup>0</sup>) + lb(2<sup>1</sup>) + lb(2<sup>2</sup>) + ... + lb(2<sup>lb(lb(n))</sup>)

= 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + lb(lb(n))

= O([lb(lb(n))]<sup>2</sup>)

## Expectation analysis

Let X(i) be the random variable representing the ith term, where X(i) = lb(2<sup>i</sup>) = i with probability 1/2 and X(i) = 0 otherwise. Then E[X(i)] = i/2.

So the expectation of X(0) + X(1) + ... + X(lb(lb(n))) is just 1/2 the deterministic result above, by the linearity of expectation. That is, the expected complexity is still O([lb(lb(n))]<sup>2</sup>).

---

Note that the distinction between log (base e) and lb (base 2) is irrelevant when dealing with asymptotic complexity, since log(x) = lb(x)/lb(e) and lb(e) is a constant.

Comment: Just for clarification. According to [ISO 31-11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11#Exponential_and_logarithmic_functions) lg is the common logarithm (base 10). The binary logarithm (base 2) is lb and the natural logarithm (base e) is ln.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Interesting. In school we always used lg for base 2 (there wasn't any pure-math motivation for base 10). I'll update to use lb instead.

Comment: @NicoSchertler See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases The use of lg for base 2 is recognized.